# MVC 3 working with images

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to save images locally and retrieve them to my view. My problem is that i'm really new to MVC and all that I've tried doesn't seem to work.. If there are sites, samples or code snippets that work with locally stored images please feel free to pass on the knowledge...

Thank you

Comment: Show us what you've tried already. Do you have problems uploading the image as well? Or you're passed that point and you just don't know how to save the uploaded image? And don't know how to retrieve them and show in a view?

Comment: Im having problems doing that aswell

Comment: "I've tried doesn't seem to work" - unless you show some code of what you've tried already, your question is in danger of being closed down. You question is too broad, especially that you asking for sample codes. I suggest you post what you have tried to show that "you have tried something".

Answer (score 0):

Start out with `HttpContext.Server.MapPath("/")` in your Controller to get the folder that you are currently working in. Watch where that gives you, and adjust accordingly if you want to maintain any sort of organization.